# How to pass literal array as input argument of the function?

Tags: c, arrays

The goal is to pass a constant array, (representing the member variables of the corresponding structure parameter) like `{{"network", "lan"}, {"dhcp", "true"}}`  as parameter when calling a function like:

```
ubus_call("router", "client", {{"network", "lan"}, {"dhcp", "true"}}, 2);
```

I tried the following code but it returns errors in the compilation:

```
struct ubus_args {
 char *key;
 char *val;
};

int ubus_call(char *obj, char *method, struct ubus_args u_args[], int size_args) {
 printf("%s\n", obj);
 printf("%s\n", method);
 printf("%s  %s\n", u_args->key, u_args->val);
 return 0;
}

int main ()
{
  ubus_call("router", "client", {{"network", "lan"}, {"dhcp", "true"}}, 2);
  return 0;
}
```

How I can do that in the proper way?

Comment: compound literals, maybe?

Comment: "but it returns errors in the compilation:"  --> post the error message.

Comment: Step 1, use`int ubus_call(const char *obj, const char *method, const struct ubus_args *u_args, size_t size_args)`

Comment: `struct ubus_args` itself should have `const char *` instead of `char *`, since you are putting string literals in it.  String literals are not writable.

Answer (score 10):

Here is the complete program, you can try it out.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct ubus_args {
    char *key;
    char *val;
};

int ubus_call(char *obj, char *method, struct ubus_args u_args[], int size_args) {
    printf("%s\n", obj);
    printf("%s\n", method);
    printf("%s  %s\n", u_args[0].key, u_args[0].val);
    printf("%s  %s\n", u_args[1].key, u_args[1].val);
    return 0;
}

int main ()
{
    ubus_call("router", "client", (struct ubus_args[2]){{"network", "lan"}, {"dhcp", "true"}}, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

The program is tested on `GNU GCC v4.8.3` online compiler.

Comment: If it is not intended for `ubus_call` to modify the strings, use `const struct ubus_args` in both the function parameter and the compound literal

Answer (score 8):

If you're equipped with a `C99` and above supported compiler, you can use [compound literals](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html) to get your job done.

You can rewrite the function call like

```
ubus_call("router", "client", (struct ubus_args[]){{"network", "lan"}, {"dhcp", "true"}}, 2);
```

and it will work.

<kbd>[LIVE DEMO](http://ideone.com/fFC9EE)</kbd>

BTW, the recommended signature of `main()` is `int main(void)`.